# AutoEncoder shape

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I try to create a autoencoder in Tensorflow without using contriib.
Here is the original code

https://github.com/Machinelearninguru/Deep_Learning/blob/master/TensorFlow/neural_networks/autoencoder/simple_autoencoder.py

Here is the program I modify:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




ae_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 1))  # input to the network (MNIST images)


xi = tf.nn.conv2d(ae_inputs, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])), 
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')
print("xi {0}".format(xi))

xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,16])), 
                 strides=[1,2,2,32],
                 padding='SAME')
print("xi {0}".format(xi))

xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,16,8])), 
                 strides=[1,4,4,16],
                 padding='SAME')
print("xi {0}".format(xi))






xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xi, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,16,8])), 
                 output_shape=[1, 8, 8, 16],
                 strides=[1,4,4,1],
                 padding='SAME')
print("xo {0}".format(xo))

xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,16])), 
                 output_shape=[1, 16, 16, 32],
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')
print("xo {0}".format(xo))

xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo, 
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])), 
                 output_shape=[1, 32, 32, 1],
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')

print("xo {0}".format(xo))
```

And the result from the print  is that:

> xi Tensor("Conv2D:0", shape=(?, 16, 16, 32), dtype=float32) 
>   xi Tensor("Conv2D_1:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 16), dtype=float32) 
>   xi Tensor("Conv2D_2:0", shape=(?, 2, 2, 8), dtype=float32)
>   xo Tensor("conv2d_transpose:0", shape=(1, 8, 8, 16), dtype=float32) 
>   xo Tensor("conv2d_transpose_1:0", shape=(1, 16, 16, 32), dtype=float32)
>   xo Tensor("conv2d_transpose_2:0", shape=(1, 32, 32, 1), dtype=float32)

It seems the output has the good shape but I don't really sure about all the parameters in the conv2 and conv2_transpose.

Can someone correct my code if needed

edit: 
@Lau I add the relu function as you tel me but I don't known where to add the bias:

```
xi = tf.nn.conv2d(ae_inputs,
             filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
             strides=[1,2,2,1],
             padding='SAME')
xi = tf.nn.relu(xi)
# xi = max_pool(xi,2)
print("xi {0}".format(xi))

xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi,
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,16])),
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')
xi = tf.nn.relu(xi)
# xi = max_pool(xi,2)
print("xi {0}".format(xi))

xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi,
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,16,8])),
                 strides=[1,4,4,1],
                 padding='SAME')
xi = tf.nn.relu(xi)
# xi = max_pool(xi,4)
print("xi {0}".format(xi))






xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xi,
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,16,8])),
                 output_shape=[tf.shape(xi)[0], 8, 8, 16],
                 strides=[1,4,4,1],
                 padding='SAME')
xo = tf.nn.relu(xo)

print("xo {0}".format(xo))

xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo,
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,16])),
                 output_shape=[tf.shape(xo)[0], 16, 16, 32],
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')
xo = tf.nn.relu(xo)

print("xo {0}".format(xo))

xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo,
                 filter=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
                 output_shape=[tf.shape(xo)[0], 32, 32, 1],
                 strides=[1,2,2,1],
                 padding='SAME')
xo = tf.nn.tanh(xo)
print("xo {0}".format(xo))
return xo
```

I don't understand what is the difference with the original code:

```
# encoder
# 32 x 32 x 1   ->  16 x 16 x 32
# 16 x 16 x 32  ->  8 x 8 x 16
# 8 x 8 x 16    ->  2 x 2 x 8
print('inputs {0}'.format(inputs))

net = lays.conv2d(inputs, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
print('net {0}'.format(net))

net = lays.conv2d(net, 16, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
print('net {0}'.format(net))

net = lays.conv2d(net, 8, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
print('net {0}'.format(net))

# decoder
# 2 x 2 x 8    ->  8 x 8 x 16
# 8 x 8 x 16   ->  16 x 16 x 32
# 16 x 16 x 32  ->  32 x 32 x 1
net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
print('net {0}'.format(net))

net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
print('net {0}'.format(net))

net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 1, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)

print('net {0}'.format(net))
return net
```

Edit2 :

@Lau I make the new version of the autoencoder with your modifications:

```
mean = 0
    stdvev = 0.1
    with tf.name_scope('L0'):
        xi = tf.nn.conv2d(ae_inputs,
                     filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,1,32], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                     strides=[1,1,1,1],
                     padding='SAME')
        xi =  tf.nn.bias_add(xi, bias_variable([32]))
        xi = max_pool(xi,2)
        print("xi {0}".format(xi))

    with tf.name_scope('L1'):
        xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi,
                         filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,32,16], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                         strides=[1,1,1,1],
                         padding='SAME')
        xi =  tf.nn.bias_add(xi, bias_variable([16]))
        xi = max_pool(xi,2)
        print("xi {0}".format(xi))

    with tf.name_scope('L2'):
        xi = tf.nn.conv2d(xi,
                         filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,16,8], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                         strides=[1,1,1,1],
                         padding='SAME')
        xi =  tf.nn.bias_add(xi, bias_variable([8]))
        xi = max_pool(xi,4)
        print("xi {0}".format(xi))


    with tf.name_scope('L3'):
        xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xi,
                         filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,16,8], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                         output_shape=[tf.shape(xi)[0], 8, 8, 16],
                         strides=[1,4,4,1],
                         padding='SAME')
        xo =  tf.nn.bias_add(xo, bias_variable([16]))
        print("xo {0}".format(xo))

    with tf.name_scope('L4'):
        xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo,
                         filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,32,16], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                         output_shape=[tf.shape(xo)[0], 16, 16, 32],
                         strides=[1,2,2,1],
                         padding='SAME')
        xo =  tf.nn.bias_add(xo, bias_variable([32]))
        print("xo {0}".format(xo))

    with tf.name_scope('L5'):
        xo = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xo,
                         filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,1,32], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
                         output_shape=[tf.shape(xo)[0], 32, 32, 1],
                         strides=[1,2,2,1],
                         padding='SAME')
        xo =  tf.nn.bias_add(xo, bias_variable([1]))
        xo = tf.nn.tanh(xo)
        print("xo {0}".format(xo))
```

But the result is the same, the decoded value are not the same.

Edit3:

I change thefilter definition from

```
filter=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,16,8], mean = mean, stddev=stdvev),
```

to

```
 filter= tf.get_variable('filter2',[5,5,16,8]),
```

The result seems to converge to better result but still converge to a different value. In the original code (0.006) and my version 0.015. I think it comes from the initialize value of the filter and the bias. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a bias and an activation. So your network is weaker than a PCA. I suggest you use `tf.layers`instead. If you want to use `tf.nn`, then please use `tf.get_variable`.
Furthermore you have to add:
`tf.nn.bias_add` 
`tf.nn.relu` (or any other activation)

If you want to know if the code works just test it with:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tf.global_variables_initializer())
test_output = sess.run(xo, feed_dict={ae_inputs : np.random.random((1, 32, 32, 1))}
print(test_output)
```

**EDIT**
Ok, so the code you posted uses basically the `tf.layers` API, where bias and activation is included. The `tf.nn` API is more basic and only applies convolution, but without activation or bias.

Based on your edit I think you want to implement the the CAE in the nn API. A typical encoder layer would be this:

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                     nput=input_tensor,
                     filter=tf.get_variable("conv_weight_name", shape=[height,
                                                                width,
                                                                number_input_feature_maps,
                                                                number_output_feature_maps]),
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding="SAME")
bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, tf.get_variable("name_bias",
                                            [number_output_feature_maps]))
layer_out = tf.nn.relu(bias)
```

Here is a typical layer for transpose convolution.

```
conv_transpose = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=input_tensor,
                       filter=tf.get_variable("deconnv_weight_name", shape=[height,
                                                                     width,
                                                                     number_output_feature_maps,
                                                                     number_input_feature_maps]),
                       output_shape=[batc_size, height_output, width_ouput, feature_maps_output],
                       strides=[1, 1, 1, 1])
bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_transpose, tf.get_variable("name_bias", shape=[number_output_feature_maps]))

layer_out = tf.nn.relu(bias)
           `
```

If you have questions about the names, just ask in the commnets.

Comment: I answer you in my original post

Comment: Can you additionally post the link of the source? I extend my answer later

Comment: Thank you I add the link

Comment: I publish the modifications in the original post. It seems I get other result but is still doesn't fit

Comment: You forgot the activation. By default a relu is applied in the conv layers of the source, but not in the tf.nn layers. Can you please specify nwhat exactly is different? Values or shapes ?

Comment: Should I really put an activation function if you tell me there is not in tf.nn.layers? The result is not good because in the original model when I put a mnist image as input I get the same image in output. In my model the output images stay black

Comment: The code basis works now, please post a new question, where you ask, why your AE does not work. If you do not use an activation your method is not an AE, but an PCA. The reasons why activations is missing in `tf.nn` is because its a more basic API. As I said `tf.layers`is the correpsonging one to `tf.contrib.layers`